# What are the common misuse of using STL containers with iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

What are the common misuse of using [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) containers with iterators?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Forgetting that iterators are quite often invalidated if you change the container by inserting or erasing container members.

For many great tips on using STL I **highly** recommend Scott Meyers's book "Effective STL" ([sanitised Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629))

Comment: I generally agree, but it's possible to interpret your statement as "Iterators are *always* invalidated by insertions or deletions."  Vector iterators are never invalidated by deleting a *later* element, and neither insertions nor deletions of other elements invalidate list, set and map iterators.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: that's true, i'll edit my response

Answer (score 9):

The end range check should be using != and not < since the order of the pointers isn't guaranteed.

Example:

```
for(it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Ouch!  Your C++ Standard Library implementation must be using (typedefs of) raw pointer types as iterators -- for exactly this reason, it's much safer to  implement all iterators as distinct types that wrap pointers, with suitable operator overloads (e.g. for operator==() but not operator<()).

Comment: Yeah, was a while since I did c++ to be honest. Never had any issues with it myself since I mostly used vectors. This is one of the things I remember from Exceptional C++ by Herb Sutter. (Or some other similar book)

Comment: You have a typo - you should be comparing "it != list.end()", not "it != list.end".  Otherwise you're comparing against the address of a function!

Answer (score 8):

Post-incrementing when pre-incrementing will do.

Comment: I can't say this is a big deal as it doesn't compromise code correctness, and surely a decent optimising compiler will generate identical code whenever the original, pre-increment value of i++ is not used?  (Mind you I always pre-inc just in case...)  FTR: I didn't -1 you (didn't +1 you either...).

Comment: @j_random_hacker, completely agree that it's not a big deal but it is a common STL iterator idiom.  The question didn't  specify what specific types issues he was concerned with.

Comment: The compiler can't necessarily generate identical code, depending on what the iterator really is.  i++ generates a temporary value, which can't always be optimized away.  ++i just does the increment.

Answer (score 7):

A few others:

- Converting a reverse iterator to a base iterator without remembering that the iterator will now be one element beyond the one it was pointing to.
- Trying to use algorithms that require a random-access iterator with iterators of things like sets and maps.
- Editing the key of a map entry with a non-const iterator (this happens to build on VS.Net, but won't with GCC)

Answer (score 6):

Using them without reading the "Effective STL" book by Scott Meyers. :) Really. This makes most of the stupid bugs go away.

Comment: As well have having lots of great advice and examples about how best to use the STL.

Answer (score 6):

**Proper continuation after `erase()`.**

Assuming:

```
Container::iterator i = cont.begin(), iEnd = cont.end();
```

For instance on `std::map`, this is not a good idea:

```
for (; i != iEnd; ++i) {
    if (i->second.eraseCondition()) {
        cont.erase(i);
    }
}
```

This would work:

```
for (; i != iEnd; ) {
    Container::iterator temp = i;
    ++temp;
    if (i->second.eraseCondition()) {
        cont.erase(i);
    }
    i = temp;
}
```

And this also:

```
for (; i != iEnd; ) {
    if (i->second.eraseCondition()) {
        cont.erase(i++);
    }
    else {
        ++i;
    }
}
```

It's been too many times really that I've had to apply these fixes in some production code :(

Comment: For this you should be using std::remove_if to prevent just these kinds of bugs.

Comment: @Billy: But no one does because without lambdas your code looks wordy and stupid.

Comment: @Zan: 1. Have any stats to back that up? 2. I don't know about you, but I'll take slightly "stupid" looking code in order to turn an O(n^2) algorithm into an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: @Billy: No stats, but most of the C++ programmers I really know (about 5) avoid using the STL algorithms because it moves that code off into a separate class/struct when a simple loop construct instead looks better.

Comment: @Zan: That argument holds water for something like `for_each`, but something like `remove_if` isn't easy to code by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Using an auto_ptr inside a container, e.g.

```
list<auto_ptr<int> > foo;
```

Fortunately, a lot of auto_ptr implementations these days are written to make this impossible.

Comment: Note: Use boost::shared_ptr<> instead of std::auto_ptr<> if you want to store them in a container.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't only problem with STL containers - modyfing container when iterating over it almost always leads to problems.

This is very common source of bugs in games - most game loops consists of iterating over each game object doing something. f this something adds or erases elements from game objects container there is almost surelly bug.

Solution - have two containers - objectsToDelete and objectsToAdd - in game code add objects to that containers, and update game objects container only after you iterated over it.

objetsToAdd can be Set to ensure we wont delete anything more than one time.

objectsToDelete can be Queue if you can construct Object without adding it to game objects container, or it can be some other class (ObjectCreateCommand?) if your code assumes that Object instance is always added to game objects container directly after creation (for example in constructor).

Comment: Have to extra agree with this one: I've seen the infinitely increasing object loop many times. Also seen the skipping of the item after the deleted item and even reprocessing the item before the deleted item.

Answer (score 1):

```
list<int> l1, l2;
// ...

for_each(l1.begin(), l2.end(), do_it());
```